# System.StackOverflowException When DataBind() code is fired

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two dropdown lists one is working and one is not with the exact same code.

the first one that is working correctly has a ddlist.databind() within a TRY that when fired does NOT cause an infinite loop of going back to the begining of the code every time the databind() code is hit. Again this one is working the way I want it to. On dropdownlist3 every time the databind() happens it restarts the code at the begining of the the Sub

Dropdownlist1 (Working correctly) code behind

```
Protected Sub DropDownlist1_DataBinding1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim O1IDText As String = DirectCast(FindControlRecursive(Me.Page, "HFO1ID"), HiddenField).Value
    Dim ddList As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)

    RemoveHandler ddList.DataBinding, AddressOf DropDownlist1_DataBinding1
    Dim li As New ListItem("REMOVE / NO Official Scheduled", "", True)
    Dim li3 As New ListItem("▲▲▲▲ Current Selected Official ▲▲▲▲", "", True)
    Dim li4 As New ListItem("▼▼▼▼ All Available Officials ▼▼▼▼", "", True)


    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Try
        ddList.DataBind()

    Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Dropdownlist3 (NOT working correctly) code behind:

```
Protected Sub DropDownlist3_DataBinding3(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim O2IDText As String = DirectCast(FindControlRecursive(Me.Page, "HFO2ID"), HiddenField).Value
    Dim ddList As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)

    RemoveHandler ddList.DataBinding, AddressOf DropDownlist1_DataBinding1
    Dim li As New ListItem("REMOVE / NO Official Scheduled", "", True)
    Dim li3 As New ListItem("▲▲▲▲ Current Selected Official ▲▲▲▲", "", True)
    Dim li4 As New ListItem("▼▼▼▼ All Available Officials ▼▼▼▼", "", True)

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Try
            ddList.DataBind()

        Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

I cannot figure out why one does an infinite loop and the other does not.

here is the asp code for each drop down list:

Dropdownlist1:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostback="True" OnDataBinding="DropDownlist1_DataBinding1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="FullName" Height="24px" Width="193px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Official1") %>' >
```

DropDownlist3:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostback="True" OnDataBinding="DropDownlist3_DataBinding3" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="FullName" Height="25px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Official2") %>' Width="203px">
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my own problem

I never changed the ending of:

```
RemoveHandler ddList.DataBinding, AddressOf DropDownlist1_DataBinding1
```

I needed to change this line to:

```
RemoveHandler ddList.DataBinding, AddressOf DropDownlist3_DataBinding3
```